# Navigation Controller's view as a subview in a ViewController

Tags: ios, uikit

I am making an iPad app.

I want my app's design to include part of the screen the size of an iPhone, this will have a form styled grouped table view. The user can use this to edit/add info.

One of the form table view's "buttons" (row) will have a disclosure icon as the accessory view and when tapped I want to slide in place of that table another view.

Ideally I would add a `UINavigationController's` view to a section on the screen (on the view controller's view) say:

```
CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2, 20, 320, 400);
```

But as the Apple documentation says, you shouldn't use a Navigation Controller this way (as a subview on an existing view controller).

What can I do to imitate or workaround to get this?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen it done, and it does bring some glitches regarding viewWillAppear/willRotate/etc methods on controllers you show inside it.

The workaround is to manually call viewWillAppear / etc on the nav controller when adding it / removing it, but it's not the best way to go.

The other way to go is to show this controller on a non-dismissable popover, which you can achieve by implementing the UIPopoverController delegate function:

```
- (BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
    return NO;
}
```

Which will make the user unable to dismiss it by clicking outside of it. The popover you can show from a bar button item (which will auto-positionate after rotation), or from a rect (you will have to re-position it after rotation), but you can show no Popover Direction Arrow, to make it "hover" over your parent view controller.

Comment: It appears on the screen, but I can't resize it! I'm trying this:     `UIViewController *editVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
editVC.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0, 480.0);
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:editVC];
navController.view.frame = CGRectMake(20.0, 20.0, 320.0, 480.0);
[self.view addSubview:navController.view];`

Comment: In a nutshell, I've got it on my view... but I can't seem to resize it to the desired dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIView that will fit in that area, and have that view host the table and anything else you want. If you need to "push" views as the navigation bar would, you can use view animation or the transition methods of UIView. If I were doing this, I could create a "helper" class that managed all those views and controls - or at least a category on your existing class - so as to not clutter up your primary class.